# Scroll unfocused window under mouse

Tags: mouse, touchpad, mouse-scroll

In OS X, when you scroll with the mouse wheel/trackpad, the window that get’s scrolled is the one under the mouse, even if inactive, not necessarily the focused one. Something like [WizMouse](http://lifehacker.com/5146250/wizmouse-adds-scrolling-to-out-of-focus-windows) on Windows, it seems.

How can I achieve the same in “Vanilla” Ubuntu (GNOME)?

Comment: You really should mention what release of Ubuntu you're on & confirm if you are using a gnome session (gnome-shell). scrolling in an unfocused window is currently broken in 13.10/14.04 but only when using compiz. Should be ok in a gnome-session, works here in a 13.10 install with gnome-shell

Comment: I see that it’s a bug. If you add your comment as a question, I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is a bug in 13.10 & 14.04

The specific to scrolling in an unfocused window is here -

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1240957

May be useful to note that there are 2 additional related bugs though these 2 only are seen if bindings are set in the `ViewPort Switcher` plugin for `Desktop-based Viewport Switching`

https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1200829

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1184159

As far as 13.10 & 14.04 a fix is stalled until 2 commits are accepted into xorg-server. Also 13.10 would need some gtk fixes that have only been done for 14.04

Until such time that both gtk3 & xorg-server are fixed in 13.10 they only way around all 3 bugs is to revert the orig. offending commit in gtk3. Doing so could expose the bug that orig. commit was applied for, but it is a somewhat obscure bug, I never seen it myself.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1046988

So for those that wish, this ppa has a reverted gtk for 13.10 that will 'fix' the 3 current scrolling bugs.

(It also has a patched xorg-xserver for those using 14.04

I'll maintain the ppa until no longer needed

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/test-scroll